# Regular Expression Not Equal is not working in C# string array

Tags: c#, regex

I researched this and cannot figure out why `?!` doesn't do a Not Equal in my code.

The code has this :

```
var policyOne = "C";
var policyTwo = "GF1";
var policyThree = "018"
string policyNumber = $"^(?!{Regex.Escape(policyOne)}){Regex.Escape(policyTwo)}{Regex.Escape(policyTwo)}$",
```

So while I have also tried  `?!.*` ,  I still cannot get it to recognize that the policyOne is NOT allowed to be "C"

All 3 of the variables are joined together in a sql linq where clause

I can provide more details if needed.

This is my code

```
string AnyStart = "XXXDEFGHI";
string AnythingMiddle = "ABCXXXGHI";
string AnyEnds = "ABCDEFZZZ";

List<string> Strings = new List<string>()
{
    AnythingMiddle,
    AnyStart,
    AnyEnds
};

string hcdpPlnCvgCD = "ABC";
string HcdpPmtFctrCd = "DEF";
string hccCpmtFctrCd = "GHI";



var patterns = new string[]{
                $"^(?!{Regex.Escape(hcdpPlnCvgCD)}){Regex.Escape(HcdpPmtFctrCd)}{Regex.Escape(hccCpmtFctrCd)}$",
                $"^{Regex.Escape(hcdpPlnCvgCD)}(?!.*{Regex.Escape(HcdpPmtFctrCd)}){Regex.Escape(hccCpmtFctrCd)}$",
                $"^{Regex.Escape(hcdpPlnCvgCD)}{Regex.Escape(HcdpPmtFctrCd)}(?!.*{Regex.Escape(hccCpmtFctrCd)})$",
            };
            
var wildcards = new List<string>();

foreach (var pattern in patterns)
{
    var matchResult = Strings.Where(s => Regex.IsMatch(s, pattern)).ToList();
    matchResult.Dump();
}

wildcards.Dump();
```

Comment: can you please provide more context, how are you using the regex, and give some examples of values you're comparing.

Comment: Sure,  hang on @Jpsh

Comment: @Jpsh  -  There is the full code ( from linqpad )

Comment: What are you trying to do? Your `policyTwo` does not start with `policyOne`. Why not just use `^{Regex.Escape(policyTwo)}{Regex.Escape(policyTwo)}$`?

Comment: So other than me trying to create some simpler names... In the end the field in sql server is a collection of 3 fields together.    Thus   policy = policy1 + policy2 + policy3 ,    thus if I simply omit PolicyOne, then the looping over 1000's of records is not correct when  policy1 can be ANY value except "C" for example  -  so thus it can be A or ABC ,  just not C

Comment: Thus   Policy1 = "A" , Policy2 = "DEF"  Policy3 = "GHI"   ,  then that passes and finds that record from the database since that rule expression is to allow anything but "C"

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to suggest a few things, first you should be evaluating the 3 different patterns individually. Second it seems like a plan has some logic behind it so I propose a Plan class. Then you can use Linq to find the plans you want.

```
public class Plan
{
    public Plan(string planCode)
    {
        PlanCode = planCode;
        Evaluate();
    }
    
    private const string _planCoverage= "^ABC";
    private const string _planPaymentFactor= "DEF";
    private const string _planCoPaymentFactor = "GHI$";
    
    public string PlanCode { get; set; }
    public bool IsCoverage { get; set; }
    public bool IsPayment { get; set; }
    public bool IsCoPay { get; set; }
        
    private void Evaluate()
    {
        IsCoverage = Regex.IsMatch(PlanCode, _planCoverage);
        IsPayment = Regex.IsMatch(PlanCode, _planPaymentFactor);
        IsCoPay = Regex.IsMatch(PlanCode, _planCoPaymentFactor);
    }
}
```

using this class the following code should accomplish what you're trying to do

```
string anyStart = "XXXDEFGHI";
string anyMiddle = "ABCXXXGHI";
string anyEnd = "ABCDEFZZZ";

List<Plan> plans = new List<Plan>(){
    new Plan(anyStart),
    new Plan(anyMiddle),
    new Plan(anyEnd)
};
        
//what your first regex tried to accomplish
List<string>  noCoveragePlans = plans
    .Where(plan => !plan.IsCoverage && plan.IsPayment && plan.IsCoPay)
    .Select(plan => plan.PlanCode)
    .ToList();

//what your second regex tried to accomplish
List<string> noPaymentPlans = plans
    .Where(plan => plan.IsCoverage && !plan.IsPayment && plan.IsCoPay)
    .Select(plan => plan.PlanCode)
    .ToList();

//what your third regex tried to accomplish
List<string> noCoPayPlans = plans
    .Where(plan => plan.IsCoverage && plan.IsPayment && !plan.IsCoPay)
    .Select(plan => plan.PlanCode)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Oh wow,  I like that.   I have not tested it yet.    So thoughts on performance for other answer vs. this one with million times ran per day?    Also these values _planCoverage  will be passed in ,  I want to do that initialize one time , but the values come from a json file with many segments loaded into ... and ran thus the method has a parameter of these strings  so like    public static void CheckPattern(string _planCoverage ....  etc..  )       thoughts?

Comment: it's very subjective and really depends on what you're trying to accomplish but overall, yes class can be used on millions of records. I'd really have to know more about your specific situation to tell.